# force SSL+WWW in CakePHP .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, cakephp

I know the topic "How to force HTTPS + WWW" is often discussed and solved, and in general it works for me.

But as I now got a specific predefined .htaccess from CakePHP I do not know how to include it.

**.htaccess for CakePHP:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I put the normal code for HTTPS/WWW Forcing in front or backwards to that code, it does not work properly because all requests are set to root directory and not to e.g. /contact.

**Normally I am using:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

But you can not just include that above...

Could anybody please help me **including** HTTPS/WWW Forcing in the above .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks LazyOne, this maybe working, but for me it often ended up in "mydomain.com/redirect:/app/webroot/index.php" which was really strange. But maybe this is due to the **"{REQUEST_URI}"** because I had to change my

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

due to strange problems with redirect (no idea what happend, CakePHP suddenly requestet a **"Redirect:Controller"** as also described here http://groups.google.com/group/croogo/browse_thread/thread/55539dabfd0191fd?pli=1 - any idea about this?).

It is now **working** with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]   

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 7):

The generic way is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

No need to hard-code domain name. Also request will not redirect to root when switching from http to https

Comment: This should be the final accepted answer. Hardcoding domain name is bad business.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https and www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# route all requests for non-existing resources to CakePHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

another way might be to force SSL using a component ? http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lemon/2008/07/07/component-for-forcing-a-secure-connection